# Trying to update the list of an entity

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, relational-database

So my setup is the following:
SupportTicket - contains a list of SupportTicketMessags called Messages.
SupportTicketMessage - contains a UserProfile and a message

I'm trying to add a SupportTicketMessage to the list of my existing SupportTicket with the following method:

```
public void AddReply(string message, UserProfile author)
{
    using (ContextDb db = new ContextDb())
    {
        SupportTicketMessage msg = new SupportTicketMessage(author, message);
        Messages.Add(msg);
        db.UserProfiles.Attach(Owner);
        db.Entry(this).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

However whenever I attempt to do this I get the following error:

*An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.*

At the following line:

```
db.Entry(this).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

To sum it up:
I'm adding an object to the list and would like that object to be saved into the database.
How can I do this?

Comment: Why are you explicitly changing the state?

Comment: @Cam Bruce
Well I've added an element to the list so I want it to update

Comment: I'm just looking for a solution - I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to explicitly change the state of the object. Entity Framework does that for you automatically.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? How can I add the element of the list to the database?

Comment: add it to the db table collection like such: `db.SupportTicketMessages.Add(msg);` , then call the `Save()` method.

Comment: But how can I add it to the list in the SupportTicket then? I mean it will get added to the database - sure - but it wont be contained in the list

Comment: You can add it to both the list and save it back to the database.